# Using delegated events with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX script for refreshing data and in this case calls a PHP script to display updated data to the index page within a certain div. The issue I am having is it contains dynamic links. On initial page load the links work fine. If new divs which contain new links is added from the AJAX auto update script, those links are not clickable unless I refresh the page.

So I have been researching this and it appears I have tracked it down and it comes down to needing to use delegated events and binding the link. I am not savvy with Javascript nor JQuery and AJAX. So am unsure how to apply it to my current script that refreshes the PHP script with the dynamic links.

This is my script for refreshing the PHP script.

```
function auto_load(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "inc/alertsUS.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $("#svrAlertsUS").html(data);
          } 
        });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready

});

//Refresh auto_load() function after 10000 milliseconds
setInterval(auto_load,55000);
```

This is a snipped of how the URLs in the php script are generated.

```
  $AlertData .= "<a href='#{$eventID}' data-toggle='modal' data-backdrop='false' data-target='#{$eventID}'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>\n";
```

Then where I want to display the data on the page I just add...

```
<div id="svrAlertsUS"></div>
```

Any suggestions how how I can resolve this?

Comment: What are the links supposed to do? The concept of "delegated events" applies when you are using event handlers defined in JavaScript, but in the code shown you're not doing that. Given you have an `href='#something'` are the links just supposed to navigate to specific elements on the current page?

Comment: The links open Bootsrap modals which have dynamic generated information. The links are dynamic too as they are based off the ID of the information for which it is generating that comes from a JSON file. Hence why the link is #{$eventID} so it opens its own unique modal.